# What is the error Illegal mix of collations?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

What is the error Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='?

I cannot login to my site http://homeodisha.com/

User ID : demo
Password: demo

Thanks!!!

Comment: (I not sure is it good idea, you have just posted an username/password). You should include lots of information like table schema, how to you perform mysql connection in php.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query to  `WHERE username=_utf8 'username_text' AND password =_utf8 'password_text'`

Comment: Hi A1 In my table structure the fl_accounts table has mix collection for e.g. Username varchar(255)  utf8_general_ci and Password  varchar(255) utf8_unicode_ci. Do I need to change all Mix collection to utf8_unicode_ci or utf8_general_ci?